# Can countability coexist with infinity?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, elementary-set-theory, infinity

This question concerns the countability of the real numbers.
First I will show how I count the numbers between 0 and 1 on the real line.
It is done by reversing digits behind the coma, so
that e.g. 0,761 maps to 167. Obviously this is 1 to 1 mapping,
but there are infinite number of those unique mappings depending on the chosen reasonable radix.
In decimal number system I could count numbers like this:

### $
0 , 0.1 , 0.2 , 0.3 ... 0.9 , \\
0.01 , 0.11 , 0.21 , 0.31 , ... , 0.91 , \\
0.02 , 0.12 , 0.22 , 0.32 , ... , 0.92 , \\
0.03 , 0.13 , 0.23 , 0.33 , \dots , 0.93 , \\
\vdots \\
0.09 , 0.19 , 0.29 , 0.39 , \dots , 0.99 , \\
0.001 , 0.101 , 0.201 , 0.301 , \dots , 0.901 , \\
\vdots \\
0.002 , \dots , 0.902, \\
\vdots \\
0.092, \dots , 0.992 , \\
0.003 , \dots , 0.903 , \\
\vdots \\
0.004, \dots , 0,904,\\
\vdots \\
\infty \\
$

Now, given that I can "succeed" to count to infinity, I would also count all irrational numbers.
There is no reason to haste. But then all irrational numbers are "somewhere" in the infinity.
So either counting to infinity allows me to write irrational numbers backwards, or infinity and countability can not coexist. 
Which one is true ? How does your solution compare to rational numbers ?

Comment: No, your "counting" of the numbers in $[0,1]$ is missing **all** numbers with non terminating decimal digits, for example, $\frac 1 3=0.33\dots$ which is rational, and in particular **all** irrational numbers.

Comment: An almost identical argument was posted on MO recently, and it was commented there why is fails.

Comment: That was exactly the point of my question. I thought I would come closer to them when I continue to count, that they will appear in the sequence at certain point.

Comment: Why would you think that? Try and count to "$\cdots333$" from $1$. You can't; it's not an integer. Perhaps you tacitly think "counting" can include ordinal induction (in which one can "count" beyond countable infinitiy), but you need to restrict yourself to the actual definition of counting: putting things in bijection with $\bf N$.

Comment: I thought this was kind of shuffled bijection. I thought in infinity there must be enough place, so I can arrive to 1/3 . It is just the ordering, isn't it ?

Comment: What do you mean by "in infinity"? Please restrict yourself to referring to precise mathematical concepts. When you're counting things, the only infinity you're allowed is $\bf N$ to put things in bijection with. You can't say any infinity contains everything by fiat.

Comment: @anon True, I thought infinity of **N**. Every number between [0,1) is mapped to exactly one number in **N**. I should have stated that.

Comment: @rivocantus That is not true. What number in $\mathbb{N}$ does 0.33333... map to?

Comment: @anon I do not have the space to write it, as much as I do not have the space to write the largest number in **N**. If I could it would certainly have its precise place. The point is that I can continue writing my **R** sequence endlessly in the same manner as I can continue writing **N** endlessly without ever making the mistake, so to say I will include all numbers at the end, and they will map 1 to 1.

Comment: There is no largest number in $\mathbb{N}$.

Comment: Again you are making the unjustified step of saying you "will include all numbers in the end." Why?  Where will you include the number $1/3$?

Comment: @wilson That was the question: is there contradiction between countability and infinity ? I wonder.

Comment: What do you mean by "contradiction between countability and infinity"?  Note that some sets are both countable and infinite, like $\mathbb{N}$. (We call these "countably infinite".)

Comment: Also, you say "that was the question" referring to whether $1/3$ appears in the list, but your posted question claims that it "obviously" does.  So do you claim to have a proof, or not?  If so, you need to justify the suspect step I pointed out, or it is not a proof.

Comment: @wilson But if there is some bijecion between [0,1) and **N** , and [0,1) is not countable ? I can not elaborate proof now, I would like some firmer way to dismiss my argument (intuition).

Comment: There is no bijection between $[0,1)$ and $\mathbb{N}$.  The reason you cannot elaborate on your proposed proof is because you do not really have a proof.  Your intuition is wrong.  It happens to all of us at some point -- all it means is that you need to revise your intuition in light of the facts.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's denote the $n^\text{th}$ number in your list by $f(n)$.
To use your method to prove that $[0,1)$ is countable, you need to show that $f$ is a surjection, that is, for every real number $x \in [0,1)$ there is a natural number $n$ such that $f(n) = x$.  In particular, you have to show that there is a natural number $n$ such that $f(n) = 1/3$.
Note that $n$ here is just an ordinary, *finite*, natural number.
So you have to show that $1/3$ appears at some finite stage in your list (*e.g.* it is the tenth number listed, or the millionth number listed.)

This is not the case, and it is not correct to argue that it must appear sometime because $\mathbb{N}$ is so very large.  For no value $n \in \mathbb{N}$ do we have $f(n)=1/3$, any more than we have $f(n) = -1$ or $f(n) = 37$.  These numbers simply do not appear in the list.

Comment: @rivocantus Ok, I changed $[0,1]$ to $[0,1)$ in my answer.  The idea is the same.  I do not suggest that $\mathbb{N}$ is also uncountable.  It is not.  Personally I take infinity seriously because I am a set theorist. (I'm not sure what the point of that last sentence in your comment was, however.)

Comment: @rivocantos  I should mention that the countability of $\mathbb{N}$ is immediate from the definition of "countable", so perhaps you should take another look at that definition.

Comment: @wilson How shall I prove that 1/3 does not appear in my list ?

Comment: @rivocantus One way would be to prove that for all natural numbers $k$, the first $10^k$ numbers in your list are multiples of $10^{-k}$.  So every number in your list is a multiple of $10^{-k}$ for some natural number $k$.  The number $1/3$ is not a multiple of $10^{-k}$ for any natural number $k$, so it cannot appear in your list.

Comment: (This is just an elaboration of the first comment to your question, by Peter Tamaroff.)

Comment: @wilson Thank you! I appreciate that. But 1/3 = 0.333.. so it corresponds to the natural number 333... with infinitely many 3's and it is inside **N** because **N** is infinite, and it is 1 to 1 correspondence. That is why I wrote you that infinity of natural numbers must be taken seriously. Of course I can not say where that number is in **N**, but I know that it is in ordered countable sequence. My argument does not depend on radix, it can be any, not just ten. 1/3 is a lucky example because it is palindrome. I am more concerned about reversing irrationals, when I do not know first digit.

Comment: @rivocantus  The thing is that $333...$ with infinitely many 3's is _not_ a natural number---it is _not_ in $\mathbb{N}$.  Although $\mathbb{N}$ itself is an infinite set, each member of $\mathbb{N}$ is a finite number.  An object of the form $333....$ could be considered as a _kind_ of number: see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/P-adic_number.  However, it is not a _natural number_.

Comment: @rivocantus What your argument shows is that the interval $[0,1)$ is a surjective image of the set of 10-adic numbers, not the set of natural numbers.  (And I agree that the same argument works for other radices in place of 10.)

Comment: @wilson It is true that with 333... I run into the problem with Peano axioms about natural numbers, with it's defined unique successor, because I do not know where that number is in the list, but I know it exists because I can add 1. In that way everything escapes to the domain of definitions. It seems I am merely restating the concept of infinity with 333... , and infinity itself is not a number in **N**. But that can not be true? So do we have **objects** that mimic uncountable positive integers?

Comment: @rivocantus Are you saying that because you can add 1 to 333..., it is a natural number?  I don't understand this statement.  We do have objects that mimic _infinite_ positive integers, for example the $p$-adic numbers.  I wouldn't say that they mimic _uncountable_ positive integers, however.  The set of $p$-adic numbers is uncountable, but each one only has countable many digits.

Answer (score 10):

You have only counted the numbers whose decimal expansion is finite. This covers absolutely no irrational number, and in fact not even all the rational numbers as well.

Furthermore there is absolutely no reason to expect that this sort of process is continuous. That is to say, the set of finite strings of integers is countable, but the set of infinite strings is uncountable. Even if you can approximate **one** infinite string by its finite initial segments with a countable process, you can't approximate **all** the infinite strings **at the same time** with finite approximation with a countable process.

Comment: Well, the rationals are countable and they are dense in $\bf R$, so I'd consider enumeration of $\bf Q$ a sort way of approximating them all at the same time. Ultimately, the point is that approximating all the reals and actually obtaining them all in the list are two different things.

Comment: @rivocantus: The natural intuition we come with is hardly ever applicable to infinite objects. This is why we spend time understanding the definitions, and developing *new* intuitions which suit them.

Answer (score 0):

To extend a little Peter's comment, you are assuming that you have the decimal expansion of all real numbers. Even if you find a way to extend your method to reals with infinite decimal places (such as $\pi$), there are still a countable number of them. You are missing  actually a number of reals that are uncountable and cannot be written with any algorithm: the uncomputable numbers (that is: most of the real numbers!)

Comment: well, it is known (well, if you accept the definition of infinite countable vs inf. uncountable) that the set of all computable real numbers is countable. So the number of uncomputable ones must be uncountable, as the whole set of reals. I agree that in principle (but not in practice), you can get as close to any real as you like, but that is not enough (intuition fails). Could you please give me an example, for instance, how do you write PI backwards in your sequence?

Comment: I mean, how do you start at least?

Comment: to me your statement "if natural numbers are infinite there must be place in it so that Pi can be reversed" is wrong. And I don't see any contradiction between countability and infinity.

Comment: I disagree. there is an infinite number of natural numbers, but none of them has an infinite number of digits (you assume there is one if you assume you can write pi that way). You can have a natural number with as many digits as you want, but the number will always be finite.

Comment: I don't think this is the right way to view it. *All* real numbers have decimal expansions, even if we can *compute* only countably many of them. Just like *all* real numbers are either $1$, or smaller than $1$, or greater than $1$, even if we can't tell which one it is. The problem here is not with the existence of decimal expansions, but rather with the fact that vast majority of them do not terminate, so "reversing" makes no sense.

Comment: @tomasz I agree with you. I focused on the uncomputables because, if I dont remember wrong, the question talked about picking any real and write it backwards. I just wanted to stress that there some reals for which you cannot even know the decimal expansion. I never said they didn't have it. If my answer feels confusing to you please feel free to edit and improve it. Thanks!